# Firebase Authentication is not persisted on Flutter Web

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I am using Firebase Authentication on my Flutter Web app, but the session is not persisted during refresh.

This is the package I am using.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase

This is how I am authenticating with Firebase

```
  static Future<User> handleSignInEmail(String email, String password) async {
    await init();

    final UserCredential userCredential =
        await auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password);

    assert(userCredential.user != null);
    assert(await userCredential.user.getIdToken() != null);

    final User currentUser = await userCredential.user;
    assert(userCredential.user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    print('signInEmail succeeded: $userCredential.user');

    return userCredential.user;
  }
```

If I refresh the page and call the following method, the user that is returned is null:

```
  static Future<User> getFirebaseUser() async {
    await init();
    return await auth().currentUser;
  }
```

A similar implementation using Flutter Mobile works as expected. What am I missing on the Flutter Web implementation?

Comment: Hey @dazza5000, I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @wottpal - the solution below works

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Login happens automatically and it is handled by Firebase, however in async way. More details can be found in the official documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

The trick is very simple. You need to wait for the first state change.

```
  static Future<User> getFirebaseUser() async {
    await init();
    //return await auth().currentUser;
    return await auth().onAuthStateChanged.first;
  }
```

It returns `null` if there is no signed-in user:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#onauthstatechanged

My `firebase` version:

```
firebase: 5.0.4 #https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase
```

I wrote this implementation which works on both mobile and web:

```
  static Future<FirebaseUser> getFirebaseUser() async {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.first;
    }
    return firebaseUser;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can confirm this working with `package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart` & `firebase_auth: 0.15.5+2`

Comment: I was a bit confused by the answer (which did ended up working).
You have to switch from: **return await auth().currentUser;**
to: **return await auth().onAuthStateChanged.first;**

This has nothing to do with await init().

Do we have to check for await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser? what is the benefit? 
Thank you!

Comment: For me persistence in maintained in same instance only. When I close browser window & relaunch the application session is not persisted.

Comment: Any idea how to implement this if I use StreamProvider with value of Stream<FirebaseUser> ?

Comment: @RushikeshTalokar did you solve this? I've the same issue that "when i close the browser window and then relaunch it session is not persisted"

Comment: FirebaseAuth still loses its auth sesession after page refresh. I'm using firebase_auth: ^3.0.1. There's an open ticket for this issue: github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3356

Comment: I've the same problem :/ ... any workaround?

Comment: On firebase_auth 3.3.9 the workaround would be: `final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; await _auth.authStateChanges().first;`

Comment: @RushikeshTalokar https://stackoverflow.com/a/73437019/11440760 check this to persist authentication after closing Chrome and opening a new debug session

Answer (score 5):

Extension of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58158636

In the new library version, `onAuthStateChanged` getter is not available. Instead of that use `authStateChanges()`.

```
User firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  if (firebaseUser == null) {
    firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().first;
  }
```

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html

Answer (score 2):

[Firebase Dart Package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase)

Import this pub and check the OS wherever auth is used

```
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as firebase;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

if(Platform.isIOS || Platform.isAndroid) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then(() {
        //do something
    });
} else {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() {
        //do something
    });
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem thank you. DO NOT USE THE firebase_auth PACKAGE FOR WEB!!  use the normal firebase package instead!

Comment: firebase_dart package is discontinued. Refrain from using it for new projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Flutter 3.0.5 and firebase_auth 3.6.4 and that's the only way I could make it work for web (Chrome):

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage();

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  User? currentUser;
  late StreamSubscription<User?> userSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userSubscription = FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        setState(() {
          currentUser = user;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    userSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return currentUser != null
        ? Text('User is logged in')
        : Text('User is not logged in');
  }
}
```

As I understand, you need to wait until `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` returns non null value, but in the the beginning it returns null because there's something that still initializes in the background. Same goes for `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`, it will be null until some point, so if you check it immediately, you'll be stuck in unauthorized state unless you recheck it later somehow.